# How to intercept a http request that is sent to specific IP address (server) using ZAP?

Tags: security, owasp, zap

When a button is pressed on a website, an http request (GET) is sent to this specific server (server-ip) (also not sure if this request is sent via firefox) and the server sends back (POST) data. Now what I want to do is, I want to see this http request that is being sent to this specific server using ZAP. I currently have ZAP version 2.8.0.

The website is https://ip-address:port-number. Even though I click this button (manually) and get response the back, I am not able to see this specific request in ZAP. All the http request I see in ZAP's History tab is

Method     |                     URL
GET      |  https://ip-address:portnumber/bin/bin.exe?command=...

GET |    https://ip-address:portnumber/bin/bin.exe?command=...

POST |   https://ip-address:portnumber/bin/bin.exe?command=...

I always see ip-address .. only

What I was expecting to see was the http request sent to this server.

GET | http://server-ip/...

fyi : Currently I am doing proxy localhost:port-number-1 on firefox.

Comment: This is interesting, as Firefox should proxy all calls through zap once the proxy is defined. Can you open the web console in Firefox (F12) and look at the Network tab? Click the button and document, what you see there. Maybe the button does not make any requests, just uses some local storage to process data?

Answer (score 0):

Step by step i will show you how to configure zaproxy to work fine.

1- run zaproxy

2- **Zaproxy bind port configuration**: *Tools* --> *Options* --> *Local Proxies* -->[**Address: localhost; port:8080**]
[Zaproxy bind port configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rBSV.png)

3- **Configure Certificates**: *Tools* --> *Options* --> *Dynamic SSL Certificates* --> click on *Generate* --> then save the file in your computer (it will generate news certicate File)
[**Zap Dynamic SSL Certificates**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j374G.png)

4- **Import certificates in your browser(Firefox)**:  *Preferences* --> *Privacy and Security* --> *View Certificates* --> Then import your certificate file by clicking on *import*
[**Privacy and Security**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALG6t.png)
[**Certificates importation**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QWFg.png)

5- **Configure your browser Proxy**: *Preferences* --> *General* --> *Network* *Settings* --> Check *Manual proxy configuration* --> [**HTTP Proxy: 127.0.0.1; Port:8080**]
[Browser proxy configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klG3X.png)